# How to find the leave balance month wise in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata, monthcalendar

I have sample data like this

```
EmployeeID    Begin Date      End Date    Duration  
168835        28/11/2017    28/11/2017  6   
168835        31/10/2017    9/11/2017   32
```

and I want to find the leave taken by this employee month wise,so i have joined with calendar date and i want to summarise this data monthly.For e.g, he has taken leave from 31/10/2017 to 9/11/2017 for 32 hours and 6 hours in 28/11/2017. I want to exclude weekend from 31/10/2017 to 9/11/2017 period. I have used "day of week" flag to exclude the weekends, but now problem is when i roll up the data its giving me incorrect result. basically, i want to data like duration (32+6)=38 and this should be divided no of working days that is 9 in this case, so in oct month my data should be 4.22 and in nov month it should 33.77. can anyone please help me on this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I was tracking with you until you came up with 4.22 in October. Given your sample data, where does 4.22 come from? There's only 1 day in october that this person was on leave, so what am I dividing here? Can you write out the math in your question for your desired results. Like how you would solve this manually?

Comment: I want to take total duration for both the months, in this case it is 38(32 from 31/10/2017 to 9/11/2017 and 28/11/217) and dividing by no of working days, so here total working days is 9 then divide with total duration and equally distribute between each month. so 38/9=4.22 for oct and rest of the for nov month. I hope u understood my point.

Comment: 6 and 32 is hourly duration where employee has taken leave. for example, 6 in 28/11/2017 and 32 is from 31/10/2017 to 9/11/2017.